# Possible to move specific transaction from one account to another?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core-accounts

I'm running bitcoind (0.8.0) and I'm wondering if there's a way to "move" a specific transaction from account A to account B (without actually broadcasting a new transaction). I know about the "move" command, but I can't target specific transactions with this.

Reason for this is that I'd like to use different accounts as "tags" for transactions. I want to have one single address for incoming transactions and then (after having processed them) tag them with different labels (accounts).

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to change the account associated to the address that received the transaction. Have a look at `setaccount`.

Comment: Thanks. That would imply that I have to generate a new address for every transaction. I was hoping to be able to use only one address, but I guess that's just no possible.